# CMake Finding Libraries on Wrong Path

Tags: curl, cmake

I'm trying to use CMake to use a local, 32-bit version of cURL instead of the installed 64-bit one. When I use the CMake command `find_library` it's still returning the path at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so`. I've tried using the flags NO_DEFAULT_PATH and NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH but still can't force it to look locally first. My code is below:

```
    find_library(MYCURL NAMES libcurl 
                    HINTS ${MY_CURL_DIR}
                    NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH
                    NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

Where I've specified (and verified) that `${MY_CURL_DIR}` is looking in the correct place. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you deleting your `CMakeCache.txt` between attempts?  Or more specifically, the `MYCURL` entry in your `CMakeCache.txt`.  (This file should exist in the directory you invoke CMake from).

If `find_library` successfully finds the library, further executions of CMake don't retry to find the same library.

In your command, the `NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` option is superfluous - `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` stops any paths other than `${MY_CURL_DIR}` being searched.

Also, you probably don't want to search for "libcurl", just "curl" will do.  CMake prepends "lib" for you on UNIX systems.  For more info run `cmake --help-variable CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES`

If you want to change the default caching behaviour of `find_library` and force a search every time CMake is run, use `unset` first:

```
unset(MYCURL CACHE)
find_library(MYCURL NAMES curl HINTS ${MY_CURL_DIR} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```