# SDL_image.h won't load jpg / png files?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I was using SDL2 and its extension libs under Linux. Here are the steps I took to build SDL_image lib:

1. Download libjpeg source, then standard 'configure;make;make install'
2. Download SDL_image source, standard 'configure;make;make install'

I did the same for libpng So I'll omit the steps here.

When I tried to load a jpg file and a png file, respectively, I got the following error message: (ignore the prefix added by myself. The latter part came from SDL_GetError)

```
SDL_CTexture::load error: JPEG loading error
SDL_CRenderer:copy error: Invalid texture
```

for png:

```
SDL_CTexture::load error: Failed loading png_set_longjmp_fn: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0: undefined symbol: _png_set_longjmp_fn
SDL_CRenderer:copy error: Invalid texture
```

By the way, 'make check' gave a long list of fail when I tried to build libpng. But I did installed zlib for libpng beforehand.

Any ideas?

---

PS. From output of running './configure' when building SDL_image, it said 'yes' to both libpng and libjpeg.

PPS. OK now I found out that SDL_image was getting linked to /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so, but my newly built libpng was installed in /usr/local/lib. How can I tell SDL_image to link to the newer version? I tried copying newer libs(libpng16.so) to /lib/i386-linux-gnu, but it was still referring to the old libpnf12.so.

PPPS. Finally I got it work by renaming my libpng16.so to libpng12.so.0 and copied this file to /lib/i386..., where SDL_image was referring to. However there is no decency in this solution. I'm still looking for a way to tell SDL_image that "hey use this newer libpng!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you do not compile with the correct lib release. Try to force your linker to take the right version in configure.

Have a look there http://www.willusher.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2013/08/18/lesson-3-sdl-extension-libraries/ in the qa section, a guy had the same issue as you.

This answer could also help [CMake Finding Libraries on Wrong Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796766/cmake-finding-libraries-on-wrong-path)

Comment: I'll take a look. I just edited my post would you check that plz? Thanks a lot my friend!

Comment: Your trick confirms the issue. Try to clean your cache and rebuild. Renaming the lib should not be the best fix. Good luck ;)

Comment: You are right. I tweaked configuration file for SDL2_image and now it worked like a charm. Thanks again!